# Chef cookbook - reload PATH

Tags: environment-variables, chef-infra, chef-solo

I just installed java using chef cookbook and updated PATH environment variable for all users (added new file to /etc/profile.d/).

Is it possible to tell chef to reload PATH variable?

When I do something like this:

```
execute "java_check" do
  command "java -version"
end
```

Is says that java could not be found.

It works fine when I log out, log in again and then run chef recipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure you can update the PATH variable for future chef runs, but you can set it up manually using the `environment` attribute within the `execute` stanza. This can also be used on other Resources as well. See: http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html#execute

From the Chef Docs,

```
environment
A hash of environment variables: {"ENV_VARIABLE"=>"VALUE"}.
(These environment variables must exist for a command to execute successfully.)
Default value: nil.
```

`Run a command which requires an environment variable`

```
execute "slapadd" do
  command "slapadd < /tmp/something.ldif"
  creates "/var/lib/slapd/uid.bdb"
  action :run
  environment ({'HOME' => '/home/myhome'})
end
```

Comment: You are right, probably it is not possible, to update ENV variables for future chef runs, but it is possible to update variables for future commands of current chef runs. Presented in the next post.

Answer (score 2):

I found that it is not possible to update ENV variables pemanently (to be available after chef finishes), but it is possible to update variables for future commands of current chef run.

```
ruby_block  "set-env-" do
  block { ENV[variable_name] = variable_value }
  not_if { ENV[variable_name] == variable_value }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
execute "run_updated_bash" do
    command "bash /etc/profile.d/myscript.sh"
end
```

Have you tried something like this? It could be run after you place your file in /etc/profile.d/

Comment: It didn't work for me. Script is executed successfully, but those ENV variables are exported only for this single bash context. When script is finished, they are lost.