# How to have Chef reload global PATH

Tags: linux, bash, path, chef-infra, profile

I am setting up a simple Chef recipe to install a binary app. There is no package for it in Ubuntu or CentOS so I'm writing a recipe that does the following:

1. Downloads the tar from source
2. Extracts contents from tar
3. Creates a bash script that adds the app_home to the global $PATH (it needs to be global)
4. Reloads $PATH so the current logged in user can refer to it in the shell commands

I am good up to step 3, but I cannot get Chef to reload $PATH. I have tried placing the new ***export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/app/bin*** in both `.bash_profile` as well as `/etc/profile.d/` with no success.

If I exit the shell and re-ssh I see the PATH correctly, but never in the same session as when I ran `sudo chef-client`.

Is there any way that Chef can `touch` or reload the PATH automatically so that the current logged in user can make use of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chef cookbook - reload PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313587/chef-cookbook-reload-path)

Comment: not quite, this question is not possible on Unix, period.  the other question is more reasonable to try to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No. Environment variables are inherited from the parent. A child process cannot change its parent's environment variables.

Long answer: When leveraging signals (or other forms of IPC), you could signal the parent to reload environment variables from a file.

If you have a file `~/my_environment` containing the following:

```
export FOO="bar"
```

Execute the following code in your bash:

```
function reload_environment { source ~/my_environment; }
trap reload_environment SIGHUP
reload_environment
```

Run `echo $FOO` and see it outputs `bar`

Now, when another processes sends a HUP signal to this bash process, it'll reload the environment variables in `~/my_environment` by running the `reload_environment` function.

Lets give it a try. Check what's the bash's PID by running

```
echo $$
```

Next, change the content of `~/my_environment` to:

```
export FOO="fish"
```

Then, send a SIGHUP to the bash's PID:

```
kill -HUP 12133
```

If everything went well, running `echo $FOO` on that bash session would yield `fish`

For your case, you can use inotify to send the HUP signal to bash when `~/my_environment` changes. If you're running `chef-client` from bash, you could send a HUP signal to your parent PID.

Comment: I actually tried to force Chef to `touch` or `source` the environment var file using the `execute` and `bash` resources, but it didn't work. From my understanding since the non-interactive shell made those calls it had no effect on my current interactive bash. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Indeed that was the reason :)

Answer (score 0):

why not just do:

`ENV['PATH']="#{ENV['PATH']}:/path/to/app/bin"`

In your chef cookbook?  If you've already got the additional path in there you'll wind up with it in the PATH twice, but that won't hurt anything (you can even made the assignment conditional on the additional path not being already present by adding `unless ENV['PATH'].split(/:/).include?("/path/to/app/bin")` to avoid that).

NOTE: this answer doesn't answer the original question, which isn't possible to solve.

Comment: That should work well for any child processes of chef, but will not affect the parent shell.

Comment: Okay I'm reading the question correctly now.  Yes, it is simply not possible.

Comment: note that omri.il suggested a hack that allows chef to change the parent's variables, in case the parent exposes itself for that in advance

Comment: you could always do the appropriate command to add the path in the long term, i.e. `execute 'export path = $PATH;/my/path';` followed by the above suggestion to let it function at compile time..